# Can I force the user to accept my app as lockscreen-only?

Tags: notifications, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-phone, lockscreen

My Windows 8 app needs to run a background task triggered by the receipt of raw notifications sent from Windows Phone 8 apps. Responding to that event to invoke a background task is apparently only allowed for lockscreen apps:

http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-store-app-development-10?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fdotnet+%28.NET+Zone%29

Normally, the user has control of whether they will allow an app to be a lockscreen app or not. In my case, though, it must be such or be basically braindead. So, can I enforce that: IOW, inform that users "Install this as a lockscreen app, or don't install it at all"?

What I mean is: assuming the user retains ultimate control, will letting them know that the app won't work well without them allowing it to be a lockscreen app cause it to fail certification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bet, that's how it's done.

Want to force them to allow it? Disable the "Block" button. (just kidding, you can't)

Remember, it's your app.

Check out how the Store app "supports" snap view. That's a nice example to show certification requirements can be "met" at the bare least implementation.

[image]

When you read the cert reqs. read them literally.

Comment: The "Block" button cannot be disabled by the app.  The lock screen consent dialog is shown by Windows.

Comment: You are right, the block comment was sarcasm. Hehe. Thanks for clarifying. I'm glad, "and how do you do that?" was not a follow-up question!

Answer (score 2):

> Responding to that event to invoke a background task is apparently only allowed for lockscreen apps:

Not exactly true. But anyway, the short answer to your question is **no**. And in reality, I can't see why the user would want to use your app, if it were to constantly do things in the background and thus drain their battery-life, for no good reason.

You might want to detail what your app actually will do, for more accurate advice.

Comment: I'm not going to "out" my app prematurely, but it won't be running a background task "for no good reason." Rather, I see users of it using their tablet and phone primarily to run these apps - perhaps even purchasing them in the first place for the express purpose of running these apps.

Comment: You're still not telling us what your app will do.... So we're left to draw our own conclusions. I still doubt what you're saying.

Comment: doubt away, although I don't know what it is you're doubting. As I said, I'm not going to tip my hand about what my pair of apps do.

Answer (score 1):

No, only the user decides what is, or is not, on their lock screen.  Because a user decides what is on the lock screen app list, apps preferably should provide a decent degraded experience if they are not on the lock screen.  Messaging can be provided in the application to make the user aware of the degraded experience, but again, it is ultimately up to the user.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question "will it fail certification" no. You can programmatically request that the user promote your app to the lock screen when you run, but you should consider degrading gracefully if they don't. (E.g. register for a timer event to give your app some time to periodically update itself, or send a notification through WNS and handle it then.)

While it's great to assume that your users will want to run your app under the lock screen, providing a consistent, delightful experience under different conditions is what will set you apart.